# Datagrid MouseOver and Selected States when using arrow keys

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mouseover, visualstatemanager

I have a wpf datagrid. I have added styling to show a mouseover color on a row.

What I am trying to achieve is when the mouseover appears, and a user starts using the arrow keys to navigate up and down, the mouseover needs to disappear and only the row that the user used arrow keys to get to, is the highlighted one.

The issue is the mouse cursor has been left on the grid while the user navigates with the arrow keys and the row under the cursor holds the highlight as well as the row the went to using arrows.

Here is my sample xmal:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,311,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="478" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}" 
          RowHeight="20" 
          RowHeaderWidth="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set some kind of flag when the user hits an Arrow key so that the background only changes if `IsMouseOver` and `IsUsingArrowKeys` is false. You might even be able to use the Mouse Visibility as a condition instead of using a flag

I'm not positive the exact syntax, but it should be something like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <!-- May need to reference RelativeSource here, not sure -->
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsUsingArrowKeys}" Value="False" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest highlighting the row based on thier focus triggers.

Something like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus"> 
 <EventTrigger.Actions>
   <BeginStoryboard>
     <Storyboard>
       <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="dataGrid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Green"/>
     </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
 </EventTrigger.Actions> 
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus"> 
 <EventTrigger.Actions>
  <BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="dataGrid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="White"/>
    </Storyboard>
  </BeginStoryboard>
 </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

And giving focus to them manually, something like this:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGrid1.Focus();
        }
```

So when another row gets focus, the current row loses focus & automatically falls back to non highlighted color background.